# Xamarin Forms - Disable loading spinner on ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms app where I'm using ListViews to display some data, with pull to refresh enabled.  When the ListView is pulled and starts the refresh it has its own spinner animation.  However, this doesn't display when the page first loads, and so I've wired in a separate ActivityIndicator to indicate loading for just the first time.  It's styled different though.  I would prefer to use the ActivityIndicator, since it's what's used through the rest of the app, but I haven't found a way to disable the spinner animation on the ListView yet.  Is it possible to disable it?  Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways I can think of to solve this.

1. Don't use Pull-to-refresh. Xamarin.Forms has this built in and you can't customize it without using renderers and altering controls. Instead, start your refresh another way (ToolbarItem, etc) and continue using your custom ActivityIndicator.
2. Customize the existing `ListView`s UIRefreshControl. You may be able to use a renderer or "Effect" to customize the RefreshControl being used by the native control. This would allow you to style it a little close to what your custom indicator looks like.
3. Change the color of the spinner. This is my least favorite option. You could workaround this by changing the color of the spinner to match the background so you don't see it.

Comment: I started down the route of doing a custom renderer and grabbing the UIRefreshControl, but that method is on iOS.  I don't see an obvious equilivent for Android.  Do you have any thoughts on how it'd be accomplished there?